# CSS Transition Positioning

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design. Very new. I need some help with -webkit-transitions. Is there a way i could make this so that witch ever box is transitioned always stays on top of the other boxes. Similar to the effect that happens when hovering over the box on the left.

```
<body>
<p>Test</p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>headline</h2>
        <p>test content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>headline</h2>
        <p>test content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Test</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25z7qj5d/3/

Comment: It's a strange behavior to hover event, because that mean that the elements will replace their places on hover.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly problematical as the position of the elements will move *while* you are hovering them so maintaining the hover is difficult. The speed you have chosen helps here.

Frankly the hovering is probably better suited to toggling classes with JS/JQ but the actual re-ordering *can* be done with `flexbox`.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  order: 2;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 1%;
  color: aquamarine;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.box:hover {
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>FIRST</h2>

    <p>test content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>SECOND</h2>

    <p>test content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>THIRD</h2>

    <p>test content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ojNEvM)

Answer (score -2):

here it is -

```
.animate.move {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -100px; /*.animate width*/
}
```

Please have a look [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/) for the better understanding ..

Comment: Not the requested solution/suggestion.